# Comparing data frame rows containing NAs

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two column:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 5, 6)
y <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 5, 6)

my.df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I want to keep only the rows where x != y.

What I did is this:

```
my.df <- subset(my.df, x != y)
```

What I expected was:

```
x  y
3  4
4  5
NA 0
```

What I got was

```
x  y
3  4
4  5
```

This is because, by a strange convention, `NA != 0` is `NA`.

I really want to keep the NA in the subset because I'm looking for the differences between the columns.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Just to comment on the `strange convention`: As I recall, `NA` is not considered a value in R, and therefore conditions like `!=` cannot be evaluated, leading to neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`, but `NA`.

Comment: I think I would prefer to replace all NA's with a numeric code like 999 then convert back if necessary. `my.df[is.na(my.df)] <- 999`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to create an `|` condition to get those rows having `NA` for 'x'

```
subset(my.df, x != y | is.na(x))
```

If there are also NA elements in 'y'

```
subset(my.df, x != y | is.na(x)|is.na(y))
```

Not clear about the situation where both 'x' and 'y' are NA.  If that needs to be taken out as they are same

```
subset(my.df, (x != y | is.na(x)|is.na(y)) & !(is.na(x) & is.na(y)))
```

Answer (score 5):

This would also work.
Only select rows where the subtraction of x and y are different from zero

```
my.df[!((x-y) %in% 0 ),]
```